# How do I change modally presented ViewController to be less presented, like on the image?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, storyboard

[This is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aBnJ.png)

[How it is by default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5eXE.png)

I have tried changing the frame in `viewDidLoad` of this vc

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let height = view.frame.height
    let width = view.frame.width
    let yOffset: CGFloat = +100.0 // Move down by 100 points
    let newFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: yOffset, width: width, height: height)
    view.frame = newFrame
}
```

Comment: May be `preferredContentSize` can help? If not, then you will need to implement `UIPresentationController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try looking into [UISheetPresentationController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisheetpresentationcontroller) and the concept of `Detents` which controls how much space a presented view (a sheet) should take up.

Initially you had the ability to use `.large` and `.medium` sized detents but in iOS 16 the concept of `.custom` detents was introduced, allowing you to control the sheet size yourself.

**Note** you need to set up the `sheetPresentationController` of a view when you *present* it. So you won't set this up as part of the *presented* `ViewController`s lifecycle, but instead as part of the *presenting* `ViewController` logic.

### An Example

```
@IBAction func didTapButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let viewController = PopoverViewController()

    let customDetent = UISheetPresentationController.Detent.custom(identifier: .init("myCustomDetent")) { [weak self] context in
        guard let self = self else { return 0.0 }
        return self.view.frame.height - 150.0
    }
    
    if let sheet = viewController.sheetPresentationController {
        sheet.detents = [ customDetent ]
    }

    present(viewController, animated: true)
}
```

- Here I have a `ViewController` with a `UIButton` and a function that is called when that button is tapped.
- Furthermore I have a `PopoverViewController` that will be presented when the button is tapped.
- I create a `.custom` detent with a height matching the presenting view minus 150.0 pixels.
- I add my `customDetent` to the array of `detents` that the `sheetPresentationController` of my `PopoverViewController` can use
- Finally I present the popover

Here are a couple of screenshots illustrating the process.

[image: Before tapping the button]
[image: After tapping the button]

Comment: This is exactly what I need! I appreciate your detailed answer so much. More people like you, you rock 